# Limits of Stack Exchange - what to do with useful knowledge lists

Tags: discussion

For sure is SE for high quality questions.

But where to capture important historic evolvement?

Like, adding CI Theatre to list of DevOps memes.
[What are known useful and misleading memes in the DevOps culture?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/what-are-known-useful-and-misleading-memes-in-the-devops-culture)

Do you think Wikipedia community would accepts such an article with an overview of the DevOps memes history?

Answer (score 1):

The answer below the question is community wiki, which means everyone can edit it to update it.

So, I think you already found the the place where to do those additions.

Comment: but, according to the docs there is a "community wiki post status" available via a checkbox; if I do not see it, is it due to low achievement points or to beta status of our DevOps community?

Comment: The answer to the question is already community wiki, you can't remove it and can set it again. (the edition is allowed from 100 reputation)